# Getting rank of a row in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I was using this query to assign rank to every name according to the votes they have got, but it returns with the error :

> 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Here is my code:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM table, (SELECT @rownum:=0) ORDER BY vote DESC
```

On modifying the query to this :-

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM table ORDER BY vote DESC
```

I get as expected rank of the queries as NULL. Any help , how to get rank at first place ?

**NOTE:** I am not looking for any alternative solution. Just trying to do it in the query itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. Every derived table must have its own alias. You need to alias the `(SELECT @rownum := 0)` like so:

```
SELECT 
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 
  name,
  vote 
FROM table, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t --This what you were missing an alias
ORDER BY vote DESC
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2ec/1)